# Calculating and aligning the rolling edge for print in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, alignment

I'm trying to work out how to set up the rolling edge on a circle in Adobe Illustrator.

It's for a design/pattern that will be printed on the face of a ceramic casino token, which will be wrapped around the face, along the edge and onto the reverse side.

[image: Circular design with edges that should wrap]

I know that the spacing needs to be different, so that the edges don't merge at the ends when wrapped around... But can this be calculated programmatically by any native tool?

I'm struggling to work out the best way to do the alignment to the edges/faces.

Further, the edges are very slightly curved - they aren't sharp, so what's the best way to set up my mapping of the face/edge to ensure they're joined up.

Not sure what tools/features on Illustrator best support this?

Comment: I don't really understand what's being asked. Maybe that's my shortcoming. I've read this several times and am not picking up on the problem trying to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up concentric circles showing the edge width as a circular bleed from the main design - I'd do a front and back condition, each as its own circle with circular bleed, and be sure both bleeds result in the same edge condition.

To help assure your printer or manufacturer correctly understands your design intent, I'd save trimmed versions of each - front, back and edge as symbols, and apply them as "artwork" to a 3-D extrude of a circle, so they see exactly how you wish it to end up.

[image]

Comment: I think that the function Object > Path > Split into grid might give me what I need. But I'm unsure as to the accuracy of this approach.